# I want put frame with rounds corner

Tags: mdframed, border

what is the problem? why not can a frame with round corner?

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}
    \usepackage{lipsum}
    \usepackage{float}
    \usepackage{copyrightbox}
    \makeatletter
    \renewcommand{\CRB@setcopyrightfont}{%
        \footnotesize     %footnotesize  normalsize
        \color{black}   % <--- you can select black because
                    }
    \makeatother
    \begin{document}

      \begin{figure}[H]
                \centering
                \caption{Process}
                \label{copia} 
                \copyrightbox[b]{
      \begin{mdframed}[roundcorner=10pt]
      \includegraphics[scale=0.8]{example-image}
      \end{mdframed}
      {source: asd }}
    \end{figure}

    \end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

There's a couple of things going on.

Firstly, you have your braces in the wrong place for the `\copyrightbox` macro.

You have: `\copyrightbox[b]{`*frame*`source: asd}}`, but you should have `\copyrightbox[b]{`*frame*`}{source: asd}`.

Secondly, `\copyrightbox` seems not to like the frame as its image argument. You can work around this by putting it a `\parbox`.

## MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{copyrightbox}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\CRB@setcopyrightfont}{%
  \footnotesize
  \color{black}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[H]
  \centering
  \caption{Process}
  \label{copia} 
  \copyrightbox[b]{%
    \parbox{\linewidth}{%
      \begin{mdframed}[roundcorner=10pt]
        \centering
        \includegraphics[scale=0.8]{example-image}%
      \end{mdframed}%
    }%
  }{source: asd}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Answer (score 1):

If you are okay with not using `mdframed`, I have a solution with `tikz`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
   \usepackage{tikz}
   \usepackage{float}
   \usepackage{copyrightbox}
    \begin{document}
      \begin{figure}[H]
                \centering
                \caption{Process}
                \label{copia} 
                \copyrightbox[b]{\tikz\node[draw,inner sep=5mm, rounded corners=10pt]{\includegraphics[scale=0.8]{example-image}};}
            {source: asd }
    \end{figure}
    \end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here a solution using `adjustbox` (you will need a recent version of it v1.1 or v1.2):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{copyrightbox}
\begin{document}

  \begin{figure}[H]
            \centering
            \caption{Process}
            \label{copia} 
     copyrightbox[b]{%
       \adjustimage{scale=0.8,margin=5pt,rndfbox=10pt}{example-image}
  }{source: asd }
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

or `adjustbox` all the way, without the `float` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{copyrightbox}
\begin{document}

  \begin{adjustbox}{center,captionabove={Process},label={copia},nofloat=figure}
    \copyrightbox[b]{%
      \adjustimage{scale=0.8,margin=5pt,rndfbox=10pt}{example-image}
    }{source: asd }
  \end{adjustbox}

\end{document}
```

[image]